# best way to handle blank/empty string in pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

My question is a kind of general one.  I have a dataframe with many blank/empty string in many columns with dtype object.  should I leave as it is or convert them to np.nan. What I usually do is to replace those empty string with np.nan. Is that a good practice? Thanks for any advice.

Comment: Depends on what you are doing.  If you are simply reporting and want easy to use tables.  Leave it as object.  If you want to do heavy calculations over lots of data and speed is an issue, convert to float and use `pd.to_numeric` with `errors='coerce'`

Comment: Of interest: [proposals from Wes McKinney related to this issue.](https://github.com/pydata/pandas-design/blob/master/source/internal-architecture.rst#missing-data-consistency)

Comment: @piRSquared  what I meant is object columns with  blank string in some of the rows. Majority of them are not empty.  I cannot convert those columns to numeric.

Comment: @zesla if is not numeric I guess you can't do that much.

Answer (score 0):

I've been into the same problem.
Empty cells in a dataFrame don't necessarily have to be the none type, in fact, most of the time it can be one of these: "", " ", "  ", "   " in str type. This case happens especially if you are performing a parallel corpus filtering or pre-process task in dataFrames. Anyways I dig the web found many solutions, one solution is a quite beautiful feature of python which is not so  apply to dataFrames. But Ill mention it.
As the empty list would return False such as:

`if an_object == list`

so does the strings:

`if a_str_obj == str`

But since it's not applicable in dataFrame, well except if looping over is an option - which I can't imagine why anyone would want to do that instead of implementing the great functionalities of python.

One way, you can create a function using string build in strip function using lambda. Here is the code:

```
def is_empty(a_str):
    if a_str.strip() == '':
        return 1
    else:
        return 0 

df["is_empty"] = df["str_field"].apply(lambda x: is_empty(x]))
```

> Notes on why I disagree using foor loops in dataFrames and tend to use
>   lambda even if its not the best efficient way:
>   I performed a timing test on my length = 100 dataFrame.
>   Here are the timing results:
>   **Using lambda:**
>   4.68 ms ± 79 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100 loops each)
>   **Using for loop:**
>   16.3 ms ± 38.8 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100 loops each)

Or if you care about efficiency you may use **map** function, which is **much much faster**.
Here:

```
a = list(map(is_empty, df["str_field"].values))
c = list(map(bool, a))
df[c]["is_empty"] = 1
```

It yields:
889 µs ± 22.2 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000 loops each)